# How can Momenta Affect Probability if Momenta Cancel Out to form the Probabiltiy Density Function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, spinors, spin-statistics

How does a probability density function for a wavefunction illustrate energy, momenta, or time-dependence in cases where they cancel out (even with more than one stationary state)?

Though you may not need to refer to the book, consider example 4.4 of Griffiths' *An Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, Volume 2, dealing with the Stern-Gerlach effect. Let the initial state be

$$
\chi_0=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \psi_+ \\
    \psi_- \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The ending Stern-Gerlach state is of the form

$$
\chi=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \psi_+e^{i(A+Bz)} \\
    \psi_-e^{-i(A+Bz)} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $B$ determines momentum, splitting the beam into two. My question is, when we compute the probability density function

$$
\lvert \chi \rvert^2= \begin{pmatrix}
    \psi_+^*e^{-i(A+Bz)}&\psi_-^*e^{i(A+Bz)} \\
    \end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
    \psi_+e^{i(A+Bz)} \\
    \psi_-e^{-i(A+Bz)} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

all the momenta cancel out and we get $\psi_+^*\psi_+ + \psi_-^*\psi_-$. Though the momenta values split the beam up and down, it doesn't seem to be reflected in the probability density function.

If $\psi_+$ and $\psi_-$, for example, are real unimodal Gaussians centered at 0, we end with a unimodal Gaussian centered at 0. I would expect a bimodal PDF. I can't see how the momenta affect the probability if all momenta cancel out. What am I missing?

Comment: The state is normalized so $\psi_+^*\psi_+$ and $\psi_-^*\psi_-$ are the individual probabilities you care about. Their sum is just 1.

Comment: @ConnorBehan $\psi_+$ and $\psi_-$ form the initial state, they aren't just numbers here. We're assuming the particle beam has an initial state given by $\chi(t)$ (I am ok with assuming it is Gaussian).

Comment: Do you mean that $\chi(0)$ is really a function of $x$ because $\psi_+$ and $\psi_-$ are Gaussian? If that's the case, they will not just pick up phases of $e^{\pm i (A + Bz)}$ under time evolution.